# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мыши на последнюю drop3 все drop4 показались горизонтальными?

Tags: html, css-animation

```css
ul.nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 666px;
}

ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  color: snow;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 2s
}

ul.nav li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.nav li:hover {
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav a:hover {
  background: blue;
}

ul.nav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: -40px;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -130px;
  left: 64px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">drop1</a>
        <li><a href="#">drop1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">drop2</a>
              <li><a href="#">drop2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">drop3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">drop3</a>
                    <li><a href="#">drop3</a>
                      <ul class="last">
                        <li><a href="#">drop4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">drop4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">drop4</a>
                      </ul>



                      </li>
                </ul>

                </li>
          </ul>

          </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu6</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: Картинка]

Comment: в том и дело,что не работает(

Comment: и вам надо писать правильно стили , если вы написали что li является inline-block то все li будут таковыми ..

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это должно быть

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

li{
  position:relative;
  padding:4px 10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:30%;
  background:#fff;
  }


.nav0,.nav4{display:flex;}
ul{transition:.5s;transition-delay:.4s;}

.nav1{position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;visibility:hidden;}
.nav2,.nav3,.nav4{position:absolute; top:0;left:100%;visibility:hidden;}


.nav0 li:last-child:hover .nav1,
.nav1 li:last-child:hover .nav2,
.nav2 li:last-child:hover .nav3,
.nav3 li:last-child:hover .nav4{visibility:visible;}
```

```html
<ul class="nav0">
  <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu2</a>
    <ul class="nav1">
      <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">drop1</a>
        <li><a href="#">drop1</a>
          <ul class="nav2">
            <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">drop2</a>
              <li><a href="#">drop2</a>
                <ul class="nav3">
                  <li><a href="#">drop3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">drop3</a>
                    <li class="a"><a href="#">drop3</a>
                      <ul class="nav4">
                        <li><a href="#">drop4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">drop4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">drop4</a>
                      </ul>



                      </li>
                </ul>

                </li>
          </ul>

          </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```